# When my app updates from previous version, the screen goes black. (Doesn't happen when installed for the first time)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, updates

I have an app released on the App Store and I'm developing a new update for it. I've been using testFlight and for some reason, on testFlight when upgrading from the version before, it causes the app to become an empty black screen when opened. However this does not occur if it is deleted and then installed. There is one exception to this, if I update before signing in (does not include after signing out) I also don't get the black screen. (I use firebase and google to sign in)

In addition, in this update I am switching the locations I store Data on device so I can use it for an extension. Since after signing in, I store data in the old locations, I thought it could possibly be because of this change. However, when I commented it out completely I didn't have any luck.

I also checked to make sure my Main Interface was setup correctly.

I am using SWRevealViewController as my root view controller. When this glitch happens, the view controller doesn't present either the front or the rear controller attached to it. I don't know how this would have been affected by my code. Neither the front or rear view controller calls viewDidLoad.

Any suggestions on what this may be? Here is my code in didFinishLaunching

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    notificationCenter.delegate = self
    FirebaseApp.configure()  //Firebase
    Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID //google sign-in
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self //Notifications
    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) {_,_ in }
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .blackOpaque

    // set up your background color view
    let colorView = UIView()
    colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.4)

    // use UITableViewCell.appearance() to configure
    // the default appearance of all UITableViewCells in your app
    UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = colorView

    getAllData() //function that gets all data

    if updatedToNewDataSystem == nil { //var that confirms if it was in new location (nil means no, true is yes, and false is new user)
        runWithStandardUserDefaults() //moves data to new location
    }

    signInController.setup() //check if user is signed in

    return true
}
```

Lastly, here are some logs that I found did not appear when the app was working correctly:

```
2019-10-14 16:26:40.421963-0400 SHS Assistant[443:24394] [] tcp_input [C3.1:3] flags=[R] seq=1279028434, ack=0, win=0 state=LAST_ACK rcv_nxt=1279028434, snd_una=3119232704 
2019-10-14 16:26:40.425750-0400 SHS Assistant[443:24394] [] tcp_input [C3.1:3] flags=[R] seq=1279028434, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=1279028434, snd_una=3119232704
2019-10-14 16:26:40.427276-0400 SHS Assistant[443:24394] [] tcp_input [C3.1:3] flags=[R] seq=1279028434, ack=0, win=0 state=CLOSED rcv_nxt=1279028434, snd_una=3119232704
```

I really appreciate any help I can get on this issue! Thank you in advance!